# c++ How to extend a class with composition?

Tags: c++, inheritance, encapsulation, composition

I have encountered the following problem recently. I have a Base class which has-a Base_encapsulated_class.

```
class Base_class
{
public:
    Base_class(int int_value, short short_value) :
      m_encapsulated_class(int_value, short_value)
    {};

    ~Base_class(void){};

    Base_encapsulated_class  m_encapsulated_class;
};

class Base_encapsulated_class
{
public:
    Base_encapsulated_class(int int_value, short short_value)
        : m_int(int_value),
        m_short(short_value)
    {};

    ~Base_encapsulated_class(void){};

private:
    int m_int;
    short m_short;
};
```

Now I would like to extend both the `Base_class` and the `Base_encapsulated_class`  to achieve :

```
class Derived_class : public Base_class
{
public:
    Derived_class(int int_value, short short_value, bool boolean_value) :
      Base_class(int_value, short_value)
    {};

    ~Derived_class(void)
    {};

    Derived_encapsulated_class m_encapsulated_class;

};

class Derived_encapsulated_class : public Base_encapsulated_class
{
public:
    Derived_encapsulated_class(int int_value, short short_value, bool boolean_value) :
      Base_encapsulated_class(int_value, short_value),
          m_bool(boolean_value)
    {
    }

    ~Derived_encapsulated_class(void)
    {
    }

private:
    bool m_bool;
};
```

This approach gives me two instances of `m_encapsulated_class` in the derived class object, which apparently is legal in c++ (I am bit surprised).

But this is not what I want. I want one `m_encapsulated_class` member in my derived class. So is it possible to extend the composite member in the base class?

Comment: You can't have "virtual variables" in C++ - only virtual functions.

Comment: So how do you achieve these sort of goal? I guess pass the subcomponent in via ctor and sort it as pointer or reference?

Comment: I'm no expert on OO design patterns but here are a couple of ideas. Base could have a smart pointer to `Base_encapsulated_class` , and Derived has to send a flag to Base in the constructor call to tell it which sort of object to construct.  You may have issues with privacy and encapsulation this way though, since Base and Derived can't see non-public members of Base_encapsulated etc.   Alternatively, `template<typename T = Base_encapsulated_class> class Base { ... T m_encapsulated_class; ...};` and then in Derived, `Derived(): Base<Derived_encapsulated_class>() {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a virtual getter to enforce inheritance on members :

```
class Base_class
{
public:
    Base_class(int int_value, short short_value) :
      m_encapsulated_class(int_value, short_value)
    {};

protected:
    virtual Base_encapsulated_class Get_encapsulated_class() /* = 0 if you want to enforce encapsulated derivation */
    {
       return m_encapsulated_class;
    }


private:
    Base_encapsulated_class  m_encapsulated_class;
};


class Derived_class : public Base_class
{
public:
    Derived_class(int int_value, short short_value, bool boolean_value) :
      Base_class(int_value, short_value)
    {};

    ~Derived_class(void)
    {};

protected:
    virtual Base_encapsulated_class Get_encapsulated_class() 
    {
       return m_derived_encapsulated_class;
    }

private:

    Derived_encapsulated_class m_derived_encapsulated_class;

};
```

Comment: You should really return pointer or reference to `Base_encapsulated_class` to avoid slicing

Comment: you're right. I didn't use it to avoid confusion but if OP want to use stateful methods on xxx_encapsulated_class object, it's necessary to have some kind of reference.

Comment: Bonus points for making the encapsulated class private - that alone will increate maintainability because it's clear that derived classes cannot see the private variable.